# Search for content encoding

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco it is possible to search for a document with a content `mimetype` like this:

```
@cm\:content.mimetype:text/plain
```

The [search documenatition](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#Fields_present_on_node_entries) describes this as

> Content has some additional information about the mimetype and size which can also be used in queries. These are of the form @cm:content.mimetype.

**Question**

Is it possible to search for a content *encoding*, too? This has no effect:

```
@cm\:content.encoding:UTF-8
```

Comment: The part you left out from the documentation makes me think you cannot search by encoding: In future this will also support `@cm:content.size` for the size of the content in bytes and `@cm:content.url` for the internal content url. It sounds like `size` isn't even implemented yet the wording suggests only those three criteria will be available: mimetype, size, and url.

Comment: This might also help: http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/general/non-technical-alfresco-discussion/search-encoding-06112012-1205

Comment: @RomanC Why do you think, the word 'mimetype'  should be code in this question?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Alfresco 4.2.d and in the Repository search I get results for eg. UTF-16BE encoding when searching like this:

```
 @cm\:content.encoding:UTF-16BE
```

Url: http://localhost:8080/share/page/search?t=%40cm%5C%3Acontent.encoding%3AUTF-16BE&s=&a=true&r=true

or when using the server side JavaScript search (webscript):

```
var query = "@cm\\:content.mimetype:text/plain AND @cm\\:content.encoding:UTF-16BE";
var nodes = search.luceneSearch(query, null, true, 1000);
```